# How to clear browser caches/data on multiple computers efficiently, GPO?

Tags: windows, google-chrome, active-directory, browser-cache, gpo

I want to clear the web browser cache of all computers (many) in my context.

Specifically, I want it to be Google Chrome, but I plan to expand to other browsers.

I tried to make a script that deletes the cache folder, but the cache always comes back when Google Chrome is restarted.

- Computers have w11 and w10 as operating systems
- I have an activated GPO.

Does anyone have ideas to solve this problem?